# Sitefinity > Page Templates > The Page Editor does not display anything when a .Net Core template is used

Tags: c#, .net-core, content-management-system, renderer, sitefinity

I am currently testing the new .NET Core Renderer in conjunction with the Sitefinity Quantum Demo.
I am unfortunately having problems with my page editor not working. However, this is only when I open a core template. When I start the preview mode of the template, the content is displayed to me.
I used the QuantumLayout from Sitefinity's Git for this.
My Sitefinity instance is hosted on a server in the Azure Cloud. I currently host my renderer locally for development. Later this will be hosted on the same server, but currently I'm still in mixed mode.
Does anyone have any idea why I am having this behavior???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed.
You must add the right domain in the Sitefinity Multisite options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).